# How to launch moonlight control out of browser

Tags: silverlight-4.0, moonlight

I've created Silverlight 4 control using visual studio and now I'm trying to launch it out of browser using moonlight (os openSuse 11.2). I've installed moonlight 2.99.0.7. On "Advanced" tab of moonlight configuration I've found checkbox "use firefox to execute out-of-browser application". 
But even after checking it's still impossible to use silverlight control out of browser (also this checkbox is unchecked each time when I open configuration, even if I've checked it before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When right-clicking on the Silverlight application, you should get an "Install (yourapp)" entry.

Clicking it will install your application out-of-browser.

Comment: I need to launch SL application out-of-browser using moonlight. Unfortunately latest stable moonlight version still doesn't support out-of-browser launch (at least there is no quick way to do that).